Class "GuzzleHttp\Promise" not found - but it is there
I am using CI4, php8.0, guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.9.2 & guzzlehttp/promises: 2.0.3.  While guzzle works well, when I gets to promises, it fails.
I load up the classes with:
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

I want to settle the promises like below, however, I get  Class "GuzzleHttp\Promise" not found
// Wait for all the asynchronous requests to complete
$responses = Promise::settle($promises)->wait();

My composer.json says:
"require": {
            "php": "^7.3||^8.0",
            "codeigniter4/framework": "^4",
            "phpbu/phpbu": "^6.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.9.2",
            "guzzlehttp/promises": "2.0.3",
  

In vendor, I can clearly see:
guzzlehttp->guzzle
guzzlehttp->promises
Not sure how to further debug so any pointers appreciated.

use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise;

Thank you Olivier.  I thought the promise class is available under the GuzzleHttp\Promise namespace, and I do not need to reference it as Promise\Promise?

did you try to do composer update ? just make sure to do it on local before running it in live production.

Promise is both a component of the namespace and a class name. Look at the example.

1.Update Namespace
First, ensure you are using the correct namespace. Update your use statements as follows:
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Utils;

2.Modify Code
Then, update your code to use the Utils class for handling promises:
// Wait for all the asynchronous requests to complete
$responses = Utils::settle($promises)->wait();

3.Regenerate Autoloader
Run the following command to regenerate the Composer autoloader:
composer dump-autoload


Thank you very much @Seven  Very well explained.  I will need to read more but above really helps (and works).
